# Почему "в магазине", но "на почте"?

Tags: стилистика

Тут обсуждалось уже "на балете" — "в опере", а меня интересует более прозаическая вещь: почему мы говорим "сходить В магазин", но "НА почту"? В чем разница? И там, и там речь о некоем заведении.

Answer (score 4):

Осталось по традиции от 17 века, когда были почтовые станции. Иду на почтовую станцию, на почту. Здания почтовых служб появились позже.